# XSLT Copy Node to One or More Nodes

Tags: xml, xslt-1.0

Input XML

```
<File>
    <Agency>
        <NumericAddress>111</NumericAddress>
        <TransactionCode>A</TransactionCode>
        <Producer>
            <Name>Jane Smith</Name>
        </Producer>
        <Producer>
            <Name>Joe Williams</Name>
        </Producer>
    </Agency>
    <Agency>
        <NumericAddress>222</NumericAddress>
        <TransactionCode>B</TransactionCode>
        <Producer>
            <Name>Susan Jones</Name>
        </Producer>
    </Agency>
</File>
```

Desired Output

```
<File>
    <Agency>
        <NumericAddress>111</NumericAddress>
        <TransactionCode>A</TransactionCode>
        <Producer>
            <NumericAddress>111</NumericAddress>
            <Name>Jane Smith</Name>
        </Producer>
        <Producer>
            <NumericAddress>111</NumericAddress>
            <Name>Joe Williams</Name>
        </Producer>
    </Agency>
    <Agency>
        <NumericAddress>222</NumericAddress>
        <TransactionCode>B</TransactionCode>
        <Producer>
            <NumericAddress>222</NumericAddress>
            <Name>Susan Jones</Name>
        </Producer>
    </Agency>
</File>
```

Each `<Agency>` node has at least one `<Producer>`, some may have multiples.  Each `<Agency>` node has only one `<NumericAddress>` which has a different value for each `<Agency>`.  I need to copy the `<NumericAddress>`node, for every `<Agency>`, and place it under each `<Producer>`, as shown in my Output XML.  Hopefully I explained this correctly.  How can I accomplish this with XSLT 1.0?  Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can start with an `identity template` that copies the input structure as is to the output.

```
<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" />
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Then the `Producer` node is to be modified and it's sibling element `NumericAddress` is to be copied as it's child element retaining any existing child elements. This can be done by using `<xsl:apply-templates>` and the `../` XPath feature that allows to navigate one level up from the current node.

```
<xsl:template match="Producer">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="../NumericAddress" />
        <xsl:apply-templates />
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

The complete XSLT code is as below

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" />
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Producer">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="../NumericAddress" />
            <xsl:apply-templates />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output

```
<File>
    <Agency>
        <NumericAddress>111</NumericAddress>
        <TransactionCode>A</TransactionCode>
        <Producer>
            <NumericAddress>111</NumericAddress>
            <Name>Jane Smith</Name>
        </Producer>
        <Producer>
            <NumericAddress>111</NumericAddress>
            <Name>Joe Williams</Name>
        </Producer>
    </Agency>
    <Agency>
        <NumericAddress>222</NumericAddress>
        <TransactionCode>B</TransactionCode>
        <Producer>
            <NumericAddress>222</NumericAddress>
            <Name>Susan Jones</Name>
        </Producer>
    </Agency>
</File>
```

Comment: If the answer has worked for you, could you please accept the answer. [How to accept the answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)